# No Render target selected error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a newbie so I will post what I did to get the "No render target selected" error.

Basically I have a working project on my PC in Eclipse. I decided to install Android Studio on my laptop. So I exported the Eclipse project on PC, copied the folder on to laptop
and imported the gradle file in Android Studio.

In Android Studio, when I double click the xml file in the layouts folder I get an Error: "No Render Target Selected".

In Eclipse i right clicked the project>properties and it says Taget Name Android 4.4, Platform 4.4 and API level 19
In Android stuido on my laptop, I have installed within the SDK Manager everything releated to API levels 18,19 and 20.
and I have created devices in AVD manager for platforms 4.4.2 and L.
Restarted Android Studio but still same error.

I have another tutorial project created in Android studio that has no Errors when I open the layout files.

Sub question: How do I check the target platform for the project in Android studio?

Please note I am a newbie to the Android studio/eclipse enviroments so please bare that in mind when answering.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Top menu bar on the left side of the AVD Manager button you have a "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button. Click that. Android Studio may become sluggish for like 5 seconds, but you'll also see a loading wheel in the project files tab, and possibly a yellow bar on the top of activity_main.xml tab saying that Gradle is syncing. In about 5 seconds everything will be up to date, and you will see the device as expected. Hope this helps.